# dds pub gets unmatch notification very late .. Can it be tweaked to make it quicker?

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

I am using eprosima fast dds library for a project.

Currently, on default settings, after the initial pub/sub
match - when the subscriber goes down or is removed - the
publisher get the unmatched notification after like 15 seconds

Is it possible to make it quick or instantaneous? Can anyone
point me to the right direction where I should start digging?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DDS implementation are you working with?

Comment: hi @ReinierTorenbeek I am using eprosima fast dds  (https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-DDS)